# How to run an expression to a image collection in google earth engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-earth-engine

```
// Convert the image List to an ImageCollection.
var lsCompCol = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(lsCompList);
print('finaldataset',lsCompCol);
Map.setCenter(72.91,19.13);
var lsCompCol = lsCompCol.select(
    ['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median','B5_median','B6_median','B7_median']);

// A function to compute awei.
var awei =function(image) {
image = ee.Image(image)
return image.addBands(image.expression(
  '(4*(blue-swir1))'-'((0.25*nir)'+'(2.75*swir2))',{
  'blue':image.select(['B2_median']),
  'swir1':image.select(['B6_median']),
  'swir2':image.select(['B7_median']),
  'nir':image.select(['B5_median'])
}).rename (awei).clamp(0,1));
}
lsCompCol = lsCompCol.map(awei);
var check = ee.Image(lsCompCo.first());
Map.centerObject(check);
Map.addLayer(check);

I get an error as invalid argument specified for ee.List(): function awei(_0) {
   return newF.apply(this, arguments);
```

Please help me how I can put an expression on my image collection dataset to use it further. Thanx in advance.